# Importing GeoJSON into MySQL?

Tags: geojson, import, mysql

I want to import GeoJSON data into MySQL to compare performance with other databases. Is there any way I can import following data into MySQL. And if it possible, how to create table for such records.

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":
{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-122.085823,37.386337]},"properties":
{"id":"1","name":"Frankie Johnnie & Luigo Too","address":"939 W El Camino Real, Mountain View, CA"}},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-122.083237,37.387138]},
"properties":{"id":"2","name":"Amici's East Coast Pizzeria","address":"790 Castro St, Mountain View, CA"}},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{},"properties":{"id":""}},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{},"properties":{"id":""}}]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL databases don't really support GeoJSON as such, they follow the model put forward by OGC which follows the [WKT format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-data-formats.html).

Having said that you could put your GeoJSON in a [json field](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) although thats probably not ideal as you lose access to the [spatial analysis functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-analysis-functions.html)